# Trying to implement a text slider using CSS/Javascript, having some problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So here's the code
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RELKE/)

My javascript is (probably incorrectly) as such:

```
$('#change').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if $('#change').show("slide", {
             direction: "right"
        }, 1000);
    }
});
```

The problem I'm trying to resolve is getting the "calculate" to slide off screen, and get the figure ($28.74) to slide on screen in its replace.

It's just something I'm doing for fun. I might expand it further to be more useful, but for now I just want to see how far I can get in a day of doing something from next to no actual good experience.

The

Comment: Your fiddle has errors, can you fix them first please

Comment: Your post looks incomplete, but more importantly there's a glaring syntax error relating to the `if()` statement

Comment: Okay, do you mind scratching the javascript. I really have no idea how to mangle it. Could you instead recommend how best to solve this?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/RELKE/5/ shows just the HTML/CSS. No js.

Answer (score 0):

You have written wrong syntex for if statement.You mentioned no condition for if.
Proper syntex is
`if(condition)
{
statements;
}`

For complete details,Provide with details of your Html code where you called the function.